# Apache using XAMPP shuts down unexpectedly after windows 10 upgrade

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp, windows-10

```
3:18:42 PM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
3:18:42 PM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
3:18:42 PM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
3:18:42 PM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
3:18:42 PM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
3:18:42 PM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
3:18:42 PM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
3:20:32 PM  [Apache]    Problem detected!
3:20:32 PM  [Apache]    Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!
3:20:32 PM  [Apache]    Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
3:20:32 PM  [Apache]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
3:20:32 PM  [Apache]    or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

and from xampp\apache\logs\error.log

```
[Sat Jul 30 09:13:23.898167 2016] [core:warn] [pid 5632:tid 276] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Jul 30 09:13:24.093178 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 5632:tid 276] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Jul 30 09:13:30.075520 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5632:tid 276] AH00455: Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.14 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jul 30 09:13:30.075520 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5632:tid 276] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Oct 13 2015 10:54:13
[Sat Jul 30 09:13:30.075520 2016] [core:notice] [pid 5632:tid 276] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Sat Jul 30 09:13:30.093521 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5632:tid 276] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4412
[Sat Jul 30 09:13:31.277589 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 4412:tid 288] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Jul 30 09:13:31.728615 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 4412:tid 288] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Jul 30 09:13:31.778618 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4412:tid 288] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Sat Jul 30 13:55:49.769416 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5632:tid 276] AH00428: Parent: child process 4412 exited with status 1073807364 -- Restarting.
```

I know I have fixed this before I just don't remember how I did it I anyone can help refresh my memory I would appreiciate it.

Comment: `Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!` - way before while I still used Windows, I vaguely remember skype using that port for some reason. I've no idea how to use Windows any more, but it should be easy to find some utility that can tell you which program is using port 80. Alternatively, you can configure Apache to use some other port and then just append that to your url like `http://your.local.domain:81` if you use port 81.

Comment: It's ok I'm going to close this question I remembered how to fix it. It's microsoft's damn IIS services!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the services.msc panel find "World Wide Web Publishing Service" Disabled for startup type and finally stop the process.

Comment: Windows 10 update: 'World Wide Web Service' no longer shows in _services.msc_. I found it with _Search_ for **optionalfeatures**  under the heading _Internet Information Services_.